# Issues with EDAC: filesystem remounts as read only

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, filesystem

I have searched for solutions online for days now. The closest I got to was an Arch Wiki blog with a single comment suggesting this wasn't a bug but only needed a BIOS update.

Here is what I get from `dmesg`:

```
[   14.866246] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   24.058308] int3403 thermal: probe of INT3403:03 failed with error -22
[   29.125473] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[   29.165013] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[   29.201079] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
[   29.245397] EDAC pnd2: Failed to register device with error -22.
```

I have tried `fsck` but this has not helped me since it suggested that the filesystem is already mounted. What am I doing wrong and how could I permanently resolve this? For more context, I cannot move files to Windows since the filesystem is read only. I am dual booting from an external HDD if that helps.

Comment: The error message was right, `fsck` = file system check which should be performed on an unmounted file-system.  `umount` first then `fsck`.

Comment: How should I do this if I am logged in? All file systems are now read only. I have also disable fast boot but it didn't work. I'm not (yet) an advanced Linux user, sorry!

Comment: The easiest way to `fsck` a system is boot a live system (eg. Ubuntu install media), then only thumb-drive is being used, and your hdd/ssds are not so can be freely checked...  At worst the 'live' system may use a swap partition, but it shouldn't mount any system or data partition.

Comment: I tried this but they are all mounted.

Comment: tried this?   A 'live' system won't `mount` your partition(s).  What system did you boot?  My example 'live' system was Ubuntu install media; where you select the "Try Ubuntu" and the only partition that may get used is 'swap' partition(s) (which you won't likely need to `fsck`, but can always be disabled via `swapoff`or `deactived` using gui tools anyway).

Comment: If you did boot a 'live' system & had issues (I suspect you didn't boot 'live'), you have hardware that is malfunctioning... and should start switching to checking your hardware health (ie. SMART) as the remount as RO was done for a reason, and you need to look further up your logs to find why it remounted RO.  I would check that too, but I do believe you didn't boot into a 'live' (try ubuntu) type of environment (you instead tried to boot your system normally maybe which is an installed system, not a 'live' system)

Comment: I did that ie used live boot. They were mounted. Unmounted them. Did fsck, still same error.

Comment: Anyways, the error persisted but at least my files system is no longer read only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally did(in case someone ever gets this issue) : Live boot with USB. Unmount all file systems. Use fsck.ext4 on the known error some file system(/dev/sda3) for me. Use ntfsfix on NTFS file system. Reboot. This does not solve the EDAC error. I read an Intel blog that suggested something about ECC but failed to find that in my BIOS settings.